# Rewrite in htaccess on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I made the mistake of creating a site in a folder on a test domain and now I want to redirect any traffic to that URL to the new one.

For instance I have: http://subdomain.example.com/blog and I want it to go to a complete new domain.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3):

In the htaccess file to redirect to a completely new domain you could do something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```